# How do I get the name of the class containing a logging call in Python?

Tags: python, class, logging

If I want the function name I can simply include `%(funcName)s` in the Formatter. But how do I get the name of the class containing the logging call instead?

I've gone through the documentation for `logging`, but I can't find any mentioning of it.

Comment: The reason the class name is not available by default is that while the function name is readily available from the frame object on the stack - `f.f_code.co_name` -  the class name is not. Getting the class name would impose a run-time penalty greater than the corresponding benefit - after all, you can already see exactly which file and line the call came from, which is more precise than just the class.

Answer (score 34):

For a rather easy, pythonic way to get the class name to output with your logger, simply use a logging class.

```
import logging


# Create a base class
class LoggingHandler:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)


# Create test class A that inherits the base class
class testclassa(LoggingHandler):
    def testmethod1(self):
        # call self.log.<log level> instead of logging.log.<log level>
        self.log.error("error from test class A")


# Create test class B that inherits the base class
class testclassb(LoggingHandler):
    def testmethod2(self):
        # call self.log.<log level> instead of logging.log.<log level>
        self.log.error("error from test class B")


testclassa().testmethod1()
testclassb().testmethod2()
```

By naming the logger as above, the `%(name)s` will be the name of your class

#### example output

```
$ python mymodule.py
[2016-02-03 07:12:25,624] ERROR [testclassa.testmethod1:29] error from test class A
[2016-02-03 07:12:25,624] ERROR [testclassb.testmethod2:36] error from test class B
```

#### Alternative(s)

Non-inheritance

```
import logging


def log(className):
    return logging.getLogger(className)


class testclassa:
    def testmethod1(self):
        log(self.__class__.__name__).error("error from test class A")


class testclassb:
    def testmethod2(self):
        log(self.__class__.__name__).error("error from test class B")


testclassa().testmethod1()
testclassb().testmethod2()
```

Comment: Works well as a Mixin.

Comment: Be aware that multiple classes from different modules may have the same name. It is advisable to add the module name (`self.__module__`) to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Further, be aware that you may not get the class name, where the method is defined, but the class name of the instance. For example, if `SubClass` inherits from `testclassa` and you call `testmethod1` (not overriden in the sub-class), the name of the logger is `SubClass` instead of `testclassa` . `SubClass` may be even defined in another module than `testclassa`. In that case, `self.__module__` is different from the module of the declaration of the caller method (e.g. `testmethod1`).

Answer (score 5):

You should use **extra** argument:

`views.py`

```
import logging

class SampleClass():
    def sample_func(self):
        logging.getLogger('info_logger').info('some text', extra={'className': self.__class__.__name__})
```

`logger_settings.py`

```
'format': '%(className)s | %(message)s ',
```

output log:

```
INFO | SampleClass | "some text"
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another approach if you also want the module name:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def logger(self):
        return logging.getLogger(f"{__name__}.{self.__class__.__name__}")

    def what(self, ever):
        self.logger.info("%r", ever)
```

Comment: Neat implementation!

Comment: Note: If you create a sub-class of `MyClass` in another file/module, the module name of `MyClass` is used, even though the sub-class belongs to another module. For example, if `MyClass` is defined in module `base` and the sub-class `MySubClass` of `MyClass` is defined in module `sub`, the logger name `base.MySubClass` is used instead of `sub.MySubClass`.

Answer (score 2):

There is almost certainly a better way of doing this, but until someone points that out, this will work:

```
import inspect

class testclass:
    def testmethod(self):
        log()

def log():
    stack = inspect.stack()
    try:
        print "Whole stack is:"
        print "\n".join([str(x[4]) for x in stack])
        print "-"*20
        print "Caller was %s" %(str(stack[2][4]))
    finally:
        del stack

testclass().testmethod()
```

The output of this is the following:

```
Whole stack is:
['    stack = inspect.stack()\n']
['        f()\n']
['testclass().testmethod()\n']
['                exec code in self.locals\n']
['            ret = method(*args, **kwargs)\n']
None
--------------------
Caller was ['testclass().testmethod()\n']
```

Comment: Yea I've been toying around with `inspect` too. But it feels very unpythonic. Would be super if there is a way to do the same in `logging` instead. I can't really come to think of any reason why that functionality shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

I personally just tend to name my loggers after classes, as it makes it much easier to track down where a particular message came from. So you can have a root logger named "top", and for the module "a" and class "testclass", I name my logger "top.a.testclass".

I don't see the need to otherwise retrieve the classname, since the log message should give you all the information you need.

@ed's response above, it feels very unpythonic to me and it is not something I would be comfortable with using on production code.

Comment: I'm using local logging instances for libraries, but I've never used them as local in individual classes. I guess it's the most pythonic way of doing it. But I still don't really see a reason for why the class info shouldn't be there next to the function info.

Comment: When logging to a single log file, the use of local loggers is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to make an informative log message using the representation class method:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

```
def log_message(thing: object = None, message: str = '') -> str:
    """:returns: detailed error message using reflection"""
    return '{} {}'.format(repr(thing), message)
```

This can be implemented to any class using a mix-in:

```
class UtilMixin(object):
    def log(self, message: str = '') -> str:
        """:returns: Log message formatting"""
        return log_message(thing=self, message=message)
```

You can than be associated with a class using multiple inheritance:

```
class MyClass(object, UtilMixin):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return '<{}>'.format(self)
    pass
```

**Usage**

```
logger.warning(self.log('error message goes here'))
```